# Type of object class in python is defined inside itself?

Tags: python, class

Im suposing that to generate a subclass the paternal one must be defined, if it is the case, **"object"** class must defined before the creation of **"type"** class, So, how is **"object"**, a object of **"type"** class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `object` nor `type` can be defined in pure Python: `object` because it is its own parent class and `type` because it is its own metaclass. They are provided by the Python implementation.

Comment: I'm somehow new to Python, when you say that they can't be defined in pure Python does it mean that it uses another language in the implementation?

Comment: Yes, `object` and `type` just "are" in Python, because their definitions are in the (for example) the CPython source code. This is true of any language above machine code: some concepts must be defined in the implementation, rather than in the language being implemented.